# DELETE ANY TABLE TO TEST_USER_ROLE (except one table?)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Is there any possibility to revoke "delete" from one table over "any table" privilege?

My user_role has `GRANT DELETE ANY TABLE TO TEST_USER_ROLE` privilege.

I would like leave it except one table.

I tried with `REVOKE DELETE on TEST_TABLE from TEST_USER_ROLE` but I got "cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant" error which is correct. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to revoke the ANY privilege and explicitly grant delete on the specific tables (in specific schema, of course)? You can generate the statements to do that from the data dictionary if having to find and type them all is the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revoke `DELETE ANY TABLE` and grant `DELETE`, separately. A lot of grants? Certainly, but you don't have to do it manually - write query that'll create those statements for you. Or, do it in a PL/SQL procedure, in a loop (omit table you don't want to include).

Say if you need help in composing such a code.

---

Here's a PL/SQL procedure which does the job:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_grantee varchar2(30) := 'MIKE';
  3    l_str     varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select table_name
  6                  from user_tables
  7                  where table_name <> 'DEPT'
  8                    and rownum <= 5
  9                 )
 10    loop
 11      l_str := 'grant delete on ' || cur_r.table_name || ' to ' || l_grantee;
 12      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 13      execute immediate l_str;
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
grant delete on DPT to MIKE
grant delete on TABLE_B to MIKE
grant delete on TABLE_A to MIKE
grant delete on EMPLOYEES to MIKE
grant delete on TABLE_NAME to MIKE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

. What does it do?

- line #2, `l_grantee`: user I'm going to grant the privilege to
- cursor `FOR` loop: just for example, I'll omit table `dept` and (to make a list shorter) grant `delete` for only 5 tables
- line #11: compose the `grant` statement
- line #12: display it (so that you'd have evidence of what you did)
- line #13: grant!

If there are more owners included, you'd use `ALL_TABLES` or even  `DBA_TABLES` instead of `USER_TABLES` (line #6) and include the `OWNER` column (because many users can have a table with the same name).

Comment: Sounds good but I have more than 500 tables. I need help in composing such a code:)

Comment: I added an example; have a look.